# How to sort DIVs by height?

Tags: jquery, sorting, html, height

I have three `div`s and I want to sort them by height, from largest to smallest.

```
<div>smallest</div>
<div>largest</div>
<div>middle</div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Could you post the code you have made until now?

Comment: @CasparKleijne - we'll there isn't much :) I just basically use `jQuery('div').height()` but unsure how to actually sort once I get the vals ?

Comment: @Andy You want to rearrange those DIVs on the page, or just sort the array of references?

Comment: @Sime - want to arrange on the page - actually arrange by value and store in some var and then re-arrange on page

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's quite simple. Use [`.sort()`](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/jquery-sorting-elements/):

```
$('div').sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).height() > $(b).height() ? 1 : -1;  
}).appendTo('body');
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/fEdFt/2/

Comment: Sort isn't a jQuery method, but a method on array.

Comment: @Samich - how would I about about storing the return ? i.e. so I know which div comes first, second & third etc

Comment: if you need the sorted list of this `div`s than just all get at the end of expression. Check the latest code: http://jsfiddle.net/fEdFt/4/

Answer (score 2):

Since jQuery returns an array, you can use the `sort` method on array to reorder the elements. Once they are sorted in the proper order, you can then remove them from the DOM and reinsert them in the order desired.

```
$('div.sortable').sort( function(a,b) {
   return $(b).height() - $(a).height();
}).appendTo('#container');
```

Comment: are you able to provide a jsfiddle for me ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/ might provide you a good starting point.

Comment: yeah i was wondering whether it is possible without a plugin ? i.e. just some simple raw jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall if jQuery will wrap the regular array object or not, but if not you can use a selector to get the divs and then use Array.sort(sortFunc) to sort them.

```
var divsToSort = $('div');  // I believe this returns an array object.

function sortByHeight(a, b) {
   return $(a).height() - $(b).height();
}

divsToSort.sort(sortByHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortNumber(a, b) {
            return a - b;
        }

        $(function () {
            var divOrder = [];
            $.each($('div'), function () {
                divOrder.push($(this).height());
            });


            var sortedByHeight = divOrder.sort(sortNumber);

            for (i = 0; i < sortedByHeight.length; i++) {
                $('div').eq(i).height(sortedByHeight[i]);
            }

        });
```

The html for this was:

```
<div style='border:solid 1px #ccc; width:100px; height:100px; float:left;'></div>
<div style='border:solid 1px #ccc; width:100px; height:400px; float:left;'></div>
<div style='border:solid 1px #ccc; width:100px; height:200px; float:left;'></div>
<div style='border:solid 1px #ccc; width:100px; height:300px; float:left;'></div>
```